# What makes a C/C++ program 32/64 bit?

Tags: c++, c, 32bit-64bit

I have written many programs since i learned to program about a year ago.I never could understand why i have to download separate programs for my 32 and 64 bit machines. When i write a program on one 32 bit machine it runs on my 64 bit machine. So my question what can you do in C/C++ that defines the bit type of the program?

Comment: Your OS (and ultimately your hardware) decides whether your platform is 32 or 64 bits. What is it you don't understand, *exactly*?

Comment: The difference is the size of the address space. A larger address space means more bits required for addresses (pointers). What you can do in C++ that defines the bit type is to set compiler flags telling it what kind of code to generate.

Comment: "*When i write a program on one 32 bit machine it runs on my 64 bit machine*" => No it doesn't, not directly at least. It goes through an (invisible) "emulation" layer that *makes you think* it runs seamlessly. But actually they are totally different worlds (if only because of the bus size).

Comment: "What makes a C/C++ program 32/64 bit?" Compiler.

Answer (score 6):

> What makes a C/C++ program 32/64 bit?

Whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit is baked in at compile/link time along with other things, like the target architecture.

> When i write a program on one 32 bit machine to runs on my 64 bit machine

Assuming your OS is Windows, and you're compiling the application on a 32-bit machine and outputting a 32-bit executable (i.e. not cross compiling), then Windows has a technology called [Windows on Windows64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_on_Windows) (WOW64) that allows 32-bit code to run on a 64-bit operating system.

> I never could understand why i have to download separate programs for my 32 and 64 bit machines

This isn't universally true, you only need to download some separate programs. Things like drivers interface more closely with the kernel and need to have "bitness parity". That is to say, if you have a 32-bit operating system you need 32-bit drivers and if you have a 64-bit operating system you need 64-bit drivers.

For the most part, you can get away with 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows thanks to WOW.

> So my question what can you do in C/C++ that defines the bit type of the program

Nothing. It's up to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

What really? 64 bit machines run on different CPU architecture. Theres ppc, arm, i386 etc some of the older most famous CPUs are z80 and 6502. They run a different instruction set (binary). Some 64bit processors extend or is capable of running with the instruction set of the widespread i386 cpus.

There are 64 bit CPUs that cannot run with other 64bit CPUs. 64bit binaries are definitely not compatible with 32 bit because they are missing a lot of instructions. I haven't heard of a 32bit that supports some 64bit instructions. That'd be useless too because the CPU would be slower if it cant support 64bit thus pointless to run a 64bit binary

The C/C++ compiler would generate the instructions for the machines (64bit, 32bit, arm, ppc, etc) and the instruction (also known as binary) are different. Kind of like speaking a foreign language to a machine it doesn't understand what to do

Comment: Sorry because my comment is quite useless but I really love the way you explained the concept of "architecture" and that it wasn't only 32 and 64 bit which mattered ! Good job

Answer (score 0):

On a 64-bit machine, compare the output of these two builds:

g++ -Wall -Wextra -m32 bits.cpp

g++ -Wall -Wextra -m64 bits.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << sizeof(void*) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```